# Incorrect validation button?

Tags: c#, winforms

So, I need to make an application which generates 2 numbers in 2 labels then the user has to enter the added value of these 2 numbers as answer.
Then I need to make a button which checks if the user inputed the correct solution in the textbox...

However, the check button which I made, displays answers as "incorrect" everytime... What am I doing wrong?

```
private void generatebutton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e

    {

            //Declaring Variables for Generate button
            int answer = 0;
            Random rand = new Random();
            var intNum1 = rand.Next(100, 500);
            var intNum2 = rand.Next(100, 500);
            answer = intNum1 + intNum2;


            //Generate integer number 1 in first label 
            firstnumberlabel.Text = intNum1.ToString();

            //Generate integer number 2 in second label
            secondNumberlabel.Text = intNum2.ToString();
     }

    private void checkButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)

      {
            //Declaring variables for answer label
            int userInput = 0;
            int answer = 0;
            Random rand = new Random();
            var intNum1 = rand.Next(100, 500);
            var intNum2 = rand.Next(100, 500);
            answer = intNum1 + intNum2;

            if (int.TryParse(txtanswer.Text, out userInput))
            {
                if (userInput == answer)
                {
                    // Display success message
                    MessageBox.Show("Correct!");
                }

                else 
                {
                    // Display wrong answer message
                    MessageBox.Show("Incorrect!");
                }
        }
        else
        {
            // show message that invalid input
        } 
    }

    private void exitButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        //Closes Application
        this.Close();
    }

    private void button4_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        //Clears text box
        txtanswer.Text = "";
    }
}
```

}

Comment: It is **not necessary** to repeat the tag information in the title. I removed it for a reason. Do **not** add it again. The tag system here works extremely well, and it does not need help from you.

Answer (score 0):

You're comparing the user's answer to a **new** set of random numbers, not the original two random numbers.

In your checkButton_Click event, replace the 4 lines after int answer = 0; with something like `answer = int.Parse(firstnumberlabel.Text) + int.Parse(secondnumberlabel.Text);`

There is still some input sanity checking you'll need to add to avoid exceptions in case the user tryies checking the answer without providing numbers.

Comment: Thank you. Can I add a try catch to prevent the user from inputting non-numbers?

Comment: Yes, but you would still need to be defensive against the case where the user doesn't enter anything and hits 'Check'. In that case the value will be blank. While you can handle this with try/catch exception handling, in general you want to avoid exceptions - they are very slow. You might want to look at int.TryParse() instead of the int.Parse I provided above, which will make sure the input is a number and not throw an exception if it isn't.  Edit: Uthistran's answer below shows an excellent example of how to do this using TryParse().

Answer (score 0):

Modify as below will work. you are creating new random numbers to find the answer which is wrong

```
private void generatebutton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e
{
        //Declaring Variables for Generate button
        Random rand = new Random();
        var intNum1 = rand.Next(100, 500);
        var intNum2 = rand.Next(100, 500);

        //Generate integer number 1 in first label 
        firstnumberlabel.Text = intNum1.ToString();

        //Generate integer number 2 in second label
        secondNumberlabel.Text = intNum2.ToString();
 }

private void checkButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    int userInput = 0;
    int answer = int.Parse(firstnumberlabel.Text) + int.Parse(secondnumberlabel.Text);
    if (int.TryParse(txtanswer.Text, out userInput))
    {
            if (userInput == answer)
            {
                // Display success message
                MessageBox.Show("Correct!");
            }
            else 
            {
                // Display wrong answer message
                MessageBox.Show("Incorrect!");
            }
    }
    else
    {
       MessageBox.Show("Please enter a valid answer!");
    } 
}

private void exitButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    //Closes Application
    this.Close();
}

private void button4_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    //Clears text box
    txtanswer.Text = "";
}
```